The rotation point for the BabylonJS sprite
I recently encountered a problem with the Pivot method for BabylonJS frame sprites, it does not exist :D I would like to ask if anyone has encountered a similar problem and how to set the rotation point for a sprite in BabylonJS. The main requirement for the method should be precisely the rotation of the sprite relative to some point in space, as with the center method in ThreeJS, when you bind the sprite to some point and set the center method to it in several coordinates from the desired point.


While BabylonJS Sprites don't have a direct pivot method like Three.js, you can achieve sprite rotation around a specific point using either a parent mesh or a TransformNode. Here are two approaches:
Method 1: Using Parent Mesh as Pivot
This is the simplest approach, using an invisible mesh as the pivot point:
// Create an invisible mesh to serve as our pivot point
const pivotMesh = new BABYLON.Mesh("pivot", scene);
pivotMesh.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(2, 2, 0); // Your desired pivot point

// Create the sprite
const sprite = new BABYLON.Sprite("sprite", spriteManager);

// Parent the sprite to our pivot mesh
sprite.parent = pivotMesh;

// Offset the sprite from the pivot point if needed
sprite.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 0, 0); // This will offset the sprite 1 unit to the right

// Now rotating the pivot mesh will rotate the sprite around the pivot point
pivotMesh.rotation.z = Math.PI / 4; // 45 degrees rotation

Method 2: Using TransformNode (More Flexible)
For more complex transformations, using a TransformNode might be preferable:
// Create a TransformNode to handle the pivot
const pivotTransform = new BABYLON.TransformNode("pivotTransform", scene);
pivotTransform.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(2, 2, 0); // Your pivot point

// Create the sprite
const sprite = new BABYLON.Sprite("sprite", spriteManager);
sprite.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

// Parent the sprite to the transform node
sprite.parent = pivotTransform;

// To rotate around pivot
pivotTransform.rotation.z = Math.PI / 4; // 45 degrees rotation

Animation Example
Here's how you can animate the rotation:
scene.registerBeforeRender(() => {
    pivotTransform.rotation.z += 0.01; // Continuous rotation
});

Complete Working Example
Here's a full example that you can copy and paste:
const canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);

const createScene = () => {
    const scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    
    // Create a camera
    const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("camera", 0, Math.PI / 2, 10, 
        BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), scene);
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
    
    // Create sprite manager
    const spriteManager = new BABYLON.SpriteManager("manager", "spriteSheet.png", 1, 
        { width: 64, height: 64 }, scene);
    
    // Create pivot transform
    const pivotTransform = new BABYLON.TransformNode("pivotTransform", scene);
    pivotTransform.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(2, 2, 0);
    
    // Create sprite
    const sprite = new BABYLON.Sprite("sprite", spriteManager);
    sprite.width = 1;
    sprite.height = 1;
    sprite.parent = pivotTransform;
    
    // Optional: Add visual reference for pivot point
    const pivotSphere = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateSphere("pivot", 
        { diameter: 0.2 }, scene);
    pivotSphere.position = pivotTransform.position;
    
    // Animate
    scene.registerBeforeRender(() => {
        pivotTransform.rotation.z += 0.01;
    });
    
    return scene;
};

const scene = createScene();

engine.runRenderLoop(() => {
    scene.render();
});

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    engine.resize();
});

Key Points:

Both methods maintain the sprite's local position relative to the pivot point
The TransformNode approach is more memory-efficient than creating a mesh
You can have multiple sprites share the same pivot point by parenting them to the same TransformNode/mesh
The rotation is performed in radians (use Math.PI for angle calculations)

The main advantage of using these methods is that they provide similar functionality to Three.js's center method, allowing you to bind the sprite to a specific point in space and rotate it around that point.
